# Where to find worked out examples on Exact Sequences in Homological Algebra?

Tags: homological-algebra

I am having trouble finding worked out computational examples using exact sequences.  I have searched the net some amounts looking for them - as well as looking at books such as Hatchers Algebraic Topology as well as Rotman's Intro. to Homological Algebra.   I understand a little about them but really need to find worked out examples that are at least somewhat step by step.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Did you try Aluffi's "Algebra" (online)?

Comment: Do you know about the Mayer-Vietoris sequence in homology or cohomology?

Comment: Search it here! I'm sure you can find many examples in MSE.

Comment: What do you mean precisely "examples of exact sequences
? Using exact sequences to compute things (tensor products, homology groups)?